# How to hide Empty Categories in Magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I'm in the final stages of setting up my magento 2 store. In the backend I have a process using the API to keep stock information up to date. Sometimes the stock drops to 0 for every item in a category, making it empty. If you go to one of those categories you get:

```
We can't find products matching the selection.
```

This makes sense, but I was wondering if there was a may to have magento hide the category altogether if the products in the category have no stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extension hides the empty categories from navigation menu:

https://github.com/code-x/magento2-hide-empty-categories

Comment: Hey @mukesh, thanks for the response. I've downloaded and enabled the module, it seems to be working for the most part. There are still a couple of categories not being hidden but this is definitely a step in the right direction!

Comment: Link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

From [How to hide the categories which has no product from topmenu in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232407/how-to-hide-the-categories-which-has-no-product-from-topmenu-in-magento2)

> I already checked [this](https://github.com/code-x/magento2-hide-empty-categories) but it hide the parent category as well even the child category have products

The mentioned extensions works only if empty parent categories are set to `is_anchor`.

Possible fix?

```
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $visibleCategories = [];

        /** @var Collection $categoryCollection */
        $categoryCollection = $observer->getDataByKey('category_collection');

        /** @var Category $category */
        foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
            if ($this->showCategory($category)) {
                $categoryId = $category->getId();
                $visibleCategories[$categoryId] = $categoryId;

                foreach ($category->getParentIds() as $parentId) {
                    $visibleCategories[$parentId] = $parentId;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) {
            if (!array_key_exists($category->getId(), $visibleCategories)) {
                $categoryCollection->removeItemByKey($category->getId());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     * @return bool
     */
    public function showCategory(Category $category): bool
    {
        return $category->getProductCollection()->count() > 0;
    }
```

[Module](https://github.com/sreichel/magento2-StackExchange_HideEmptyCategories)

Answer (score 0):

I tried [this module](https://github.com/gjportegies/magento2-hide-empty-categories), and it worked for me, for the most part. I believe this is the same GitHub repo as noted in the other answers to this question, I assume the author just changed the name, and that's why the other links don't work anymore.