# How to hide the categories which has no product from topmenu in Magento2

Tags: magento2

How to hide the sub-categories if they don't have any product?

I have already checked github.com/code-x/magento2-hide-empty-categories but it hides the parent category as well even the child category have products.

I don't want to hide the child categories which have products.

Comment: Check this it will help to you https://github.com/code-x/magento2-hide-empty-categories

Comment: I already checked this but it hide the parent category as well even the child category have products

Comment: For that you need to get child categories and remove that categories.