# Magento 2 Auto-remove empty categories from menu?

Tags: category, category-tree, magento2.3.1, category-listing

I am using Magento 2.3.1 and the pearl theme. My site has many different categories and I wanted to know if there is a way to have magento automatically remove  categories that don't have product in them from the menu. I don't need them to be "disabled", just not visible.

Preferably also by level, as I use some of the root categories for other things besides products (due to brand licensing). I have looked at this question:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822997/remove-empty-categories-from-magento-menu). However, that looks like it's Magento 1.7 and it also seems like a lot of work for something like this.

Comment: Best, A helping hand would be nice on this one I am looking for this since Magento 1.4

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158898)

Comment: are you talking about dominic's answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide Empty Categories in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229481/how-to-hide-empty-categories-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

One route would be template work with additional queries to work out which category to hide based on  visible product count. The other approach would be a console script which goes through categories and sets empty ones to false (otherwise true) for the visible in menu category attribute.

Which approach would you prefer?

Comment: I think the console script sounds more doable